# What planets have been destroyed in the new Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars

The Star Wars Legends canon has a large number of planets and other celestial bodies that were destroyed over the years by superweapons, natural phenomena, and other means.  Wookieepedia has a [Mundicide article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mundicide) listing these.

In the current Star Wars canon, we know that Alderaan and the Hosnian System were destroyed by the Death Star and the Starkiller Base, respectively.  Are there any other known destroyed planets or celestial bodies in the current Star Wars canon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By going through the list of [Destroyed planets](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Destroyed_planets) on Wookieepedia, and finding the planets that were destroyed in canon, there are several planets missing from your current list.

## [Anaxes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anaxes)

Anaxes was destroyed by a cataclysmic event after the end of the Clone Wars.

> Fort Anaxes was a remote military base on the planet Anaxes during the Clone Wars. After war's end, **a cataclysmic event obliterated the planet**, though miraculously, Fort Anaxes remained intact.
> <sub>[Fort Anaxes - Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/fort-anaxes)</sub>

The planet made its first appearance in "The Clone Wars: Bad Batch" part of the Lost Missions series after the *Clone Wars* TV show was cancelled.

## The [B'ankora homeworld](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/B%27ankora_homeworld)

The B'ankora homeworld, introduced for the first time (and destroyed) in the prequel novel to *Rogue One*, *Catalyst*. The homeworld is unnamed and mentioned only because Krennic sets up his scientists in the B'ankora refuge on Coruscant. Where the details are given that the B'ankora homeworld was destroyed by a cataclysmic collision with meteor, leading to the B'ankora seeking refuge on Coruscant.

<sub>I don't currently have the text to provide a quote but have read the book and can confirm the wiki's accuracy in this case.</sub>

## [Ilum](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ilum)

Originally harvested for its kyber crystals by first the Jedi and then Darth Sidious, this planet was eventually converted into the Starkiller Base superweapon by the First Order.  It was destroyed in the Resistance attack on the superweapon, which caused the planet to implode and then turn into a micro-star.

## [Polis Massa](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Polis_Massa)

Destroyed by a mysterious cataclysm some time prior to Episode III.

## [Pressy's Tumble](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pressy%27s_Tumble)

An ore-rich moon that was destroyed for easier mining.

---

Previously known planets to be destroyed are Alderaan, and the 5 planets of the Hosnian system plus their host star.

Comment: Good call.  I was able to automate that search, as it looks like Wookiepedia lets you do a category intersection.  By [intersecting](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Special:CategoryIntersection?category_1=Category%3ADestroyed_planets&category_2=Category%3ACanon+articles&limit=25&wpSubmit=Find+matches) the "Destroyed Planets" and "Canon Articles" categories, I see the planets you mentioned plus [Polis Massa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Polis_Massa) (unknown cataclysm) and [Pressy's Tumble](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pressy%27s_Tumble) (destroyed for easier mining).

Comment: Don't listen to me I'm a liar, will update accordingly when possible.

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly (though it will need to make it through the review queue).  I may update it later to match the level of detail you put into your answer, but I figure it's better to at least have it up there and less detailed than not up at all.  I haven't watched Episode IX yet, so I didn't review the intersection search to see if it's changed since my first comment, as I'd like to dodge the potential spoilers until I do watch the film.

Comment: @M.Justin, not sure why your review was rejected but I’ve approved it now. Thanks! And I’ll try to update it with any more it’s missing, and out Episode IX in spoilers.

Comment: Starkiller Base itself was a planet, so would it count?

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 It certainly does; I've updated the answer with Ilum (the planet that Starkiller Base was on), which will be visible once my edit is peer reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a *Rise of Skywalker* spoiler

> [Kijimi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kijimi) was destroyed by one of the Last Order destroyers